# Node.js Elasticsearch Mongoosastic From and Size For Pagination

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, mongoosastic

I am using [Mongoosastic](https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic/) for indexing my model to Elasticsearch  , its work very well and only problem i have its on From and Size for pagination .

according to Mongoosastic api it

> full query DSL of Elasticsearch is exposed through the search method

Based on Elasticsearch  Api [From/Size](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-request-from-size.html) i come to this code

```
music.search( {query_string:{ query:term }},{"from" : 0},{"size" : 10}, { hydrate:true }, function(err,results) { 

            console.log(results.hits.hits);
        })
```

and after runnig i come up with this error :

```
/home/app/node_modules/mongoosastic/lib/mongoosastic.js:256
        cb(null, res);
        ^
TypeError: object is not a function
    at /home/app/node_modules/mongoosastic/lib/mongoosastic.js:256:9
    at respond (/home/app/node_modules/mongoosastic/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:256:9)
    at checkRespForFailure (/home/app/node_modules/mongoosastic/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:203:7)
    at HttpConnector.<anonymous> (/home/app/node_modules/mongoosastic/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:156:7)
    at IncomingMessage.wrapper (/home/app/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3057:19)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:944:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:448:13)
```

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as I know mongoostatic doesn't support the `from/size` parameters as can be seen in [their source code](https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic/blob/master/lib/mongoosastic.js#L230). Unfortunately, it doesn't support all parameters of the ES Javascript client search function. For those who want to follow, alireza has posted [an issue](https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic/issues/77).

Comment: @Val what do you suggest ? i am gone use [Official Elasticsearch client library](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js)

Comment: If you use the official client library, you'll definitely be able to specify the `from` and `size` parameters. But since fixing Mongoostatic to support this is pretty trivial, I'd maybe wait to see what they answer in that ticket.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mongoosastic has following signature of search function:

```
schema.statics.search = function(query, options, cb) {
    // blah blah
}
```

It has 3 arguments, where second is options. Hence, your code should looks like this:

```
music.search(
    {
        query_string: {
            query: term
        }
    },
    {
        from: 0,
        size: 10,
        hydrate: true
    },
    function(err,results) {
        console.log(results.hits.hits);
    }
);
```

Comment: thanks, i just have little problem with total , when i search and i have 1 result total its more than one here is an example query with one result   `hits:
   { total: 307,
     max_score: 1.6756877,
     hits:
      [ { _id: 555371c68c9f40d9065abc3d,
          musicId: '44',
          song_id: '157117',
          __v: 0,
          created: Wed May 13 2015 20:16:14 GMT+0430 (IRDT) } ] } }` it's only 1 result but total is 307 !

Comment: `total` it's a total number of documents in index that match your query. It's not related to number of documents returned in `hits`.

Comment: how i can get count of result ?

Comment: `results.hits.hits.length` i guess?